# Char arrays accumulating unexpectedly in Cython

Tags: arrays, cython

In Cython, If I have:

```
cdef unsigned int i1[3]
cdef unsigned int i2[3]
i1 = [1, 2, 3]
i2 = [4, 5, 6]
ii = [i1, i2]
print(ii)
```

I get

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

so far so good. now, if I have:

```
cdef unsigned char c1[3]
cdef unsigned char c2[3]
c1 = bytearray(b'123')
c2 = bytearray(b'456')
cc = [c1, c2]
print(cc)
```

Or:

```
cdef unsigned char c1[3]
cdef unsigned char c2[3]
c1 = bytearray(b'123')
c2 = bytearray(b'456')
cdef unsigned char *cc[2]
cc[0] = c1
cc[1] = c2
print(cc)
```

I get:

```
[b'123', b'456123']
```

I expected `[b'123', b'456']`! What's going on?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.

Comment: How should cython know how long is the c-string cc[0] (or cc[1])? Are you aware about the convention that c-strings are null-terminated? Are c1,c2 null-terminated?

Comment: If you are doing this for self-education, then go ahead (even if doing it through cython and not directly with c definitely adds complexity). Otherwise I would give advice to stick to bytearray/typed memory views and not to mess with raw c-strings if you don’t absolutely have to.

Comment: This may come from my little experience with Cython and C in general. I was aware of the NUL termination but admittedly did not think about it. I may stick with bytes. One question out of pure curiosity though: how would I write the NUL separator in Cython if `\x00` is a valid byte value?

Comment: Writing `c1 = bytearray(b'123\0')` did the trick for me and should work.